# Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'eu-west-1' using aws java sdk 1.11.618

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk

I have upgraded awsjavasdk jar from 1.9.34 to 1.11.618 version.

I am facing Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'eu-west-1' issue when ever running the code.

Comment: Deprecated code:  
   AmazonCloudFrontClient cloudfront = new AmazonCloudFrontClient();
   cloudfront.setEndpoint(endPoint);
   cloudfront.setRegion(region);

Comment: added below code in pace of deprcated code : 
 AmazonCloudFront cloudfront = AmazonCloudFrontClientBuilder.standard()
     .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(endPoint, Regions.EU_WEST_1.getName())).build();

Comment: try changing the region in the config file in aws cli.

Answer (score 0):

According to some other posts I found, sometimes services are "regionless" and prefer us-east-1 as the region, even though the resources are in other regions.

Ref:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=821713
[AWS Cloudfront: Credential should be scoped to a valid region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603625/aws-cloudfront-credential-should-be-scoped-to-a-valid-region)

In my case, I was working with Route53 resources in Dublin, and setting the region to us-east-1 in the CLI command fixed the problem.